# Copy a string of words to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Ive been writing a program that is able to calculate a person's grades, but Im unable to turn a string into an String array (it says the array length is 1 when i put in 3 words). Below is my code. Where am I going wrong??

```
    protected static String[] getParts(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println( "What assignments make up your overall grade? (Homework, quizzes, etc)" );
    String parts = keyboard.next();     

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
    String[] assignments = pattern.split(parts);

    // to check the length

    for ( int i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++ )
        System.out.println(assignments[i]);

    return assignments;

}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

## `Scanner::nextLine`

`Scanner::next()` only consumes one word (it stops at whitespace). You want [`Scanner::nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), which consumes everything until the next line, and will pick up all your words.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboard.nextLine instead:

```
    static String[] getParts()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What assignments make up your overall grade? (Homework, quizzes, etc)");
        String[] assignments = keyboard.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (String i : assignments)
            System.out.println(i);

        return assignments;
    }
```

**NOTE:** You also do not need to define a Pattern. You also do not need to return anything since the method already prints the strings. Unless of course you plan on using the values elsewhere